# Does not respond when running error throw

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

```
create(signUpRequestDto: SignUpRequestDto): Observable<Omit<User, 'password'>> {
    this.checkUserAndThrowError(signUpRequestDto.email);
    return this.authService.hashPassword(signUpRequestDto.password).pipe(
      map(hashedPassword => {
        const user = this.userFactory.createUser(signUpRequestDto.email, hashedPassword);
        const { password, ...result } = user;
        this.userRepository.save(user);
        return result as Omit<User, 'password'>;
      }),
    );
  }

async checkUserAndThrowError(email: string): Promise<void> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { email } });
    if (user) {
      throw new AuthException(AuthExceptionType.CONFLICT_DUPLICATE_USER);
    }
  }
```

Create function throws an error when there is a user instance in line 2, but it does not end
If I catch it in the create function, it ends, but I don't want to
Please give me a better code

I wanted to throw an error in the checkUserAndThrowError function and end it

```
create(signUpRequestDto: SignUpRequestDto): Observable<Omit<User, 'password'>> {

    const user = of(this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { email: signUpRequestDto.email } }));

    if (user) {
      throw new AuthException(AuthExceptionType.CONFLICT_DUPLICATE_USER);
    }
    // this.checkUserAndThrowError(signUpRequestDto.email);
    return this.authService.hashPassword(signUpRequestDto.password).pipe(
      map(hashedPassword => {
        const user = this.userFactory.createUser(signUpRequestDto.email, hashedPassword);
        const { password, ...result } = user;
        this.userRepository.save(user);
        return result as Omit<User, 'password'>;
      }),
    );
  }
```

If you write the code like this, it runs

Comment: @nestjs/common's ExceptionFilter was used to solve it